# Windows Forms - How to access ListView's SubItems by column name?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I've tried this but it's giving me 'System.NullReferenceException':

```
    For Each MyListViewItem As ListViewItem In MyListView.Items
        MsgBox(MyListViewItem.SubItems("MyColumn").Text)
    Next
```

These lines of codes work (weird!):

```
    For Each MyListViewItem As ListViewItem In MyListView.Items
        MsgBox(MyListViewItem.SubItems(0).Text)
    Next
```

But I need to access them by column name.

I found that this code gives me blank subitem name

```
For Each MyListViewItem As ListViewItem In MyListView.Items
    MsgBox(MyListViewItem.SubItems(0).Name)
Next
```

Note that I added the columns in design time. While items in run-time:

```
    While Reader.Read
        Dim SubItems(2) As String
        SubItems(0) = Reader("ItemForMyColumn")
        SubItems(1) = Reader("ItemForSomeOtherColumn")
        MyListView.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(SubItems))
    End While
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must set the Name property of the sub-item for each individual item that you add to the list view.  It does *not* correspond to a column in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likly throwing the null reference exception when trying to access the Text property on the SubItems("MyColumn") part of your sample.

You could check to see if MyListViewItem.SubItems("MyColumn") is not null before trying to read the Text property from it.

It could also be (based on your edit) that the name you are using to look it up doesn't match that's in the SubItems list.

If you print the name that you are looking for by using the index, what do you see?

**After Edits**

I might be this wrong, but it looks like by using this [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faw83h4f.aspx) for the ListViewItem, it's only going to be getting the Text property set.

I suggest trying something like this in your init code for the ListViewItem

(Forgive me, my VB is really really rusty and I don't have VS open)

```
While Reader.Read
   Dim listViewItem As New ListViewItem()

   Dim subItem1 As New ListViewSubItem()
   subItem.Text = Reader("ItemForMyColumn")
   subItem1.Name = "MyColumn"

   //Do this as many times as you need

   listViewItem.SubItems.Add( subItem1 )

   MyListView.Items.Add( listViewItem )    
End While
```

Comment: When I use the index, it gives no exception (displaying ".Text"). Also, I'm certain that the column with that name exist. By the way, where can I find the ID? Do you mean Name?

Comment: The behavior of this ListView is weird. :(

Comment: In what way is it weird? Are you seeing other issues that might explain what's going on?

Comment: If you add a For loop over each of the SubItems and print their names, what do you see? Also, if you are getting SubItem(0) does it give you the text you are looking for?

Comment: Now we have found out why it gives me exception. But why subitems have no names? I added them during design time.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are creating and adding the SubItems at design time?

Comment: You mean from designer.vb? 'Cause I use the VS designer. Here is the generated code (by VS) --> Me.PRCList.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader() {Me.Project, Me.PRCNumber, Me.PONumber, Me.DateCreated, Me.DateApproved, Me.Type})

Comment: It's the column that I added during the design time. Subitems, during run-time.

Comment: @Brian Dishaw - Please see revisions of my questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it works! Hm, I remember I was using the same script and no exception occurred. Anyway, I'll use your codes until I found my previous scripts. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the you can get any `subitems` by its name as below:

When `add columns` dynamically

```
ListView1.Column.Add(dr("attribute_name"),dr("attribute_label"),dr("attribute_width"))
```

Then when get any `subitems`

```
ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(ListView1.Column("attribute_name").Index).Text
```